# Monthly calendar start and finish dates Ms access

Tags: ms-access, calendar

I was just wondering if it's possible in access to create a monthly calendar that accounts for the start and finish date of a task. I have seen many templates that show a single date on a monthly calendar layout in a form or a report showing something like an appointment...which again is a singular date. Im wondering if it's possible to not only show a task that has a single date but also a task that spans accross many dates and you see it on a monthly calendar. Any feedback if anyone has had luck in doing this would be great. Thank!

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Question is too broad.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try to clarify. So I have a task list with start and finish dates. some tasks are only one day long, other tasks may be 2 weeks or even a month long. So what I trying to do is create in Access a monthly calendar view that will show a task on the calendar that is either schedule to last one day, or will show the task name span across many days if that task takes more than 1 day. That way i can see overlap of tasks and understand where my team would be the most busy in the coming days, weeks or months. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand what you want. The solution will probably require lots of VBA code. Question is still too broad. You do not provide any code for analysis. Do reseach, make attempt and when you have code with specific issue, post question. Calendar db is a fairly common topic in Access forums. You might explore a Gantt chart. https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=18459